# Caching Table - Google Guava Table

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using Google Guava Table to handle table structured data in a JAVA Application. My Data-Object consists of the Table and a Map wich stores the DataTypes for each column (int, string, decimal ...).

```
public class DataTable {

    private Table<Integer, String, Object> data;
    private Map<String, Integer> types;

    private static int maxObjectSize;
    private static int rowSize;

    private DiskCache dc;

    public DataTable(){

   //Getter and Setter
```

This object can become very large and memory consuming (up to 10,000,000 rows and 16 GB memory). So my idea was to chache the to the temp-folder every 50,000 lines or so and read the data if needed.

```
public void putRow(int row, String column, Object value){
    data.put(row, column, value);
    rowSize = data.rowKeySet().size();

    if(rowSize == maxObjectSize){
        writeCache();
    }
}
```

I habe big problems of chaching the Data. On one hand it's very time consuming to cache, on the other it is hard to enshure that no data is lost and i haven't found a good third party API to chache the data.

Answer (score 0):

To the data you can either cache single values or complete rows.
To cache a single value, construct a single compound key object of row and column.

```
Cache<CompoundKey, Object> cache = ...;
Object getValue(int row, String column) {
  return cache.get(new CompoundKey(row, column));
}
```

Alternatively you can cache a complete row, by putting a map in the cache.

```
Cache<Integer, Map<String, Object> cache = ...;
Map<String, Object> getRow(int row) {
  return cache.get(row);
}
```

You use a cache like EHCache, which supports writing data to disk, if it is not fitting into the heap.

What approach you should take depends on:

- How costly is it to generate one row or value? High cost -> cache the whole row
- Only a few columns are accessed very frequently -> cache only the column value

For a cache to be useful, it requires that you can (re)generate the missing data for a specific row, and, that you have an access pattern that requests certain rows or values in a row more often. If you can only generate the whole data, or only access the complete data in one sweep, a tiny database is a valid alternative. Look for something like [mapdb](http://mapdb.org) or [leveldb](https://github.com/dain/leveldb).